# Getting invalid JSON array from array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I want to create JSON array string from array that I have. But I am getting invalid JSON.
This is what I want:

```
[
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Samer",
        "LastName": "Shame",
        "MobileNumber": "0991992993",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0991992994",
        "Name": "Abo Alshamat",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Ahmad",
        "LastName": "Ali",
        "MobileNumber": "0992993994",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0992993995",
        "Name": "AL-Kamal",
        "ID": 2
    }
]
```

And this is what I get:

```
[
    [
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Samer",
        "LastName": "Shame",
        "MobileNumber": "0991992993",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0991992994",
        "Name": "Abo Alshamat",
        "ID": 1
    ],
    [
        "validationCode": null,
        "FirstName": "Ahmad",
        "LastName": "Ali",
        "MobileNumber": "0992993994",
        "SimNumber": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PhoneNumber": "0992993995",
        "Name": "AL-Kamal",
        "ID": 2
    ]
]
```

This is code:

```
var data = [NSDictionary]()
for item in someList {
    var d = ["validationCode": null,
            "FirstName": item.prop1,
            "LastName": item.prop2,
            "MobileNumber": item.prop3...]

    data.append(d)
}
var bytes = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)
var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(bytes!, options: nil, error: nil) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

What I should do to get standard JSON format?

Comment: How are you use var d?Write more about var data and var d

Comment: I updated the code. I loop through list and create dictionaries `d` and add them in to list of dictionaries `data`. Then I convert all to JSON but I am getting `[[],[],[]]` instead of `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: Try changing [NSDictionary]() to [[String:AnyObject]]()

Comment: Tried. It doesn't work

Comment: How do you see what you get? Do you print jsonObj?

Comment: Then there you have your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting a `Swift` `CollectionType` into JSON (`bytes`) and then converting it back (`jsonObj`).

In this case `bytes` is the `JSON` as `NSData` and `jsonObj` is a Swift `CollectionType`.

So when you `print(jsonObj)` you are not printing the `JSON`, you are printing the collection.

To get the real `JSON`

```
print(NSString(data: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Here you will see the proper `JSON` format.

In Swift JSON is a String. Not an object.

---

Your code should look lie this:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: nil, error: nil)!

let jsonString = NSString(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

println(jsonString)
```

Comment: Just one sub question. When send this to web service I should send `jsonString` like you wrote here. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you send it like a normal string.

Comment: Ok. Than you very much.